# Hadoop Installation through wizard giving error

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to install a host to Hadoop cluster using wizard but its failing at below step. Please suggest what am I doing wrong here? Please see the log below.

```
Version : 4.8.0 
Release : 1.cm480.p0.50.el6 
BEGIN yum -y install cloudera-manager-agent 
Setting up Install Process 
Resolving Dependencies 
--> Running transaction check 
---> Package cloudera-manager-agent.x86_64 0:4.8.0-1.cm480.p0.50.el6 will be installed 
--> Processing Dependency: fuse for package: cloudera-manager-agent-4.8.0-1.cm480.p0.50.el6.x86_64 
--> Processing Dependency: fuse-libs for package: cloudera-manager-agent-4.8.0-1.cm480.p0.50.el6.x86_64 
--> Processing Dependency: libxslt for package: cloudera-manager-agent-4.8.0-1.cm480.p0.50.el6.x86_64 
--> Processing Dependency: cyrus-sasl-gssapi for package: cloudera-manager-agent-4.8.0-1.cm480.p0.50.el6.x86_64 
--> Processing Dependency: redhat-lsb for package: cloudera-manager-agent-4.8.0-1.cm480.p0.50.el6.x86_64 
--> Running transaction check 
---> Package cloudera-manager-agent.x86_64 0:4.8.0-1.cm480.p0.50.el6 will be installed 
--> Processing Dependency: redhat-lsb for package: cloudera-manager-agent-4.8.0-1.cm480.p0.50.el6.x86_64 
---> Package cyrus-sasl-gssapi.x86_64 0:2.1.23-15.el6_6.2 will be installed 
---> Package fuse.x86_64 0:2.8.3-4.el6 will be installed 
---> Package fuse-libs.x86_64 0:2.8.3-4.el6 will be installed 
---> Package libxslt.x86_64 0:1.1.26-2.el6_3.1 will be installed 
--> Finished Dependency Resolution 
*******Error: Package: cloudera-manager-agent-4.8.0-1.cm480.p0.50.el6.x86_64 (cloudera-manager) 
Requires: redhat-lsb******* 
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem 
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest 
END (1) 
remote package cloudera-manager-agent could not be installed, giving up 
waiting for rollback request
```

Answer (score 0):

Installed CDH 4.8 first and then through wizard add to cluster.